# Reducing object in JS wrong behavior?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use the following reduce:

```
const data = this.forms.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
       return (accumulator[current.name] = current.value);
      }
    }, {});
```

Where `this.forms` is:

```
[
{value: {document: "fsfsf", seria: "fsfsfsf"}, "name": "Form1"}, 
{value: {seria: "AA", age: "45"}, "name": "Form2"},
{value: {marry: "yes", hobby: "AAA"}, "name": "Form3"}
]
```

I need to build this result:

```
{
   "Form1":  {document: "fsfsf", seria: "fsfsfsf"},
   "Form2":  {seria: "AA", age: "45"},
   "Form3":  {marry: "yes", hobby: "AAA"}
}
```

But I get wrong result:

```
{
   {document: "fsfsf", seria: "fsfsfsf"},
   "Form2": {}
}
```

I can not get why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function to the accumulator for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) must return the accumulator to be applied to subsequent elements in the array. Returning the result of an assignment expression returns the result of the expression (`current.value` in this case), not the accumulator.

```js
const forms = [
  {value: {document: "fsfsf", seria: "fsfsfsf"}, "name": "Form1"}, 
  {value: {seria: "AA", age: "45"}, "name": "Form2"},
  {value: {marry: "yes", hobby: "AAA"}, "name": "Form3"}
];

const data = forms.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  accumulator[current.name] = current.value;
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, could I use {...accumulator} to return value instantly with the same result?

Comment: Sure, you could do that, but that will be less efficient than passing the same object reference throughout. Object creation is expensive.

Comment: Like this? ` return {...accumulator, ...[current.name] = current.formGroup.value};`?

Comment: Why use `reduce()` at all if you’re just mutating the same object? Seems unnecessarily convoluted and redundant when `forEach()` is better suited and easier to understand.

Comment: You can use `forEach` as well, but the purpose of reduce is exactly what you said: mutating an accumulator for each element in an array. `forEach` could be argued to be less appropriate because it's impure (mutates state outside of its own callback). In the hierarchy of JS functional array methods, `forEach` is the most general, with `reduce` being a specialized case of `forEach` and `map` and `filter` being specialized cases of `reduce`.

Comment: @user3573738 `({...accumulator, [current.name]: current.value})` is the one-line version, but again, this is inefficient.

Comment: `forms.map(({name, value}) => ({[name]: value})).reduce(Object.assign, {})`